# Is it possible to create a std::list in one line, specifying its values (c++)?

Tags: c++, list, stdlist

I want to create a `std::list` by specifying its values, and I'd like to do it in one line, eg :

```
std::list<std::string> myList("Cat", "Dog", "Pig"); // doesn't compile
```

I couldn't find a way to do it simply with `std::list` (I'm not satisfied with [c++ reference's examples](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/list/)), have I missed something? If it's not possible with standard lists, is there a reason? And then what is the simplest way to implement it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible in C++11

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In C++11 you can use initializer:

```
std::list<std::string> t { "cat", "dog" };
```

In C++03 [`boost::assign::list_of`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/assign/doc/index.html#list_of) is available:

```
#include <boost/assign/list_of.hpp>

std::list<std::string> t = boost::assign::list_of("cat")("dog");
```

Comment: Thanks, boost::assign::list_of is OK for me.

Answer (score 6):

Use [Boost.Assign](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/assign/doc/index.html).

```
#include <boost/assign/list_of.hpp>     
std::list<std::string> test = boost::assign::list_of("abc")("def");
```

In [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) use an initializer

```
std::list<std::string> test { "abc", "def" };
```

Answer (score 2):

in c++11 you can write

```
std::list<std::string> foo = { "bar", "meh", "bah" };
```

you'd need an up to date compiler for that. (ie gcc 4.8)

Otherwise there is no possibility in c++.

Comment: @leyasi i am sorry to hear that.

Comment: @leyasi if you don't mind the different style, you might want to take a look at the Boost Assign thing, the others suggest. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
std::list<std::string> myList { "Cat", "Dog", "Pig"};
```

C++11 only. For older C++ refer to [Boost.Assign](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/assign/doc/index.html).

```
using boost::asign::list_of;

std::list<std::string> myList = list_of("Cat")("Dog")("Pig");
```

Comment: Isn't it `using boost::assign::list_of;` ?

Answer (score 0):

In C++11 you can do this using [uniform initialization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Uniform_initialization):

```
std::list<std::string> myList{"Cat", "Dog", "Pig"};
```